# How to call a jquery plugin method using CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Im currently experimenting with jquery plugins and a thought came to me whilst messing around with jquery. Is it possible to call a jquery plugin method/function from CSS?

This is what I am trying to do:
I am currently using the textillate plugin and the [jquery scroll tracker plugin.](https://github.com/rusackas/jquery-scrolltracker) If the user goes scrolls down and the element that was using textillate is not in the viewport, then perform a textillate method to make the text fade out.

Ive managed to make the scrolltracker track my text which has the textillate method but I'm not sure on how to go on about how to called the textillates fade out method once the content is not in the view port.

I tried using this code just to test something (.container is a div where my text is in):

```
$.scrolltracker('.container');
```

and then this is in my script tag:

```
.onscreen_vert {
    color:red;
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }
```

If I get rid of the alert statement then it turns the color red when its in the viewport but when I include the alert statement, it does nothing.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: Yeah, it's doing nothing because of the massive syntax errors that the CSS parser is encountering. Interesting idea, but not doable.

Comment: css is a style sheet. its not meant to call any javascript code and never will because that is not the purpose of css. however, im not much into php but if you preprocess your css files with php maybe its possible to maneuver some coding there.